Interpolate data between points in PlotOverLine filter in paraview to get smooth plots
I have some simulation results that I want to plot in paraview over line. The problem is that the data arrays are coarsely defined and hence the change of values between two points in quite sharp.
I have tried several filters like smooth, plotoverline with custom data etc. but could not manage to get smooth curves. How should I go about it to get smooth plot over line curves?

I don't know what kind of your result or mesh structure.
Depending on whether your solution is cell-centered or point-centered, you can smooth it by applying a filter of 'Clean to grid' or 'Cell data point data' before 'plot over line'

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
